If $M$ is a module and $a$ is a nonzero divisor of $M$, then $d(M)-1=d(M/aM)$
I have seen an interesting problem while reading the dimension theory of modules.
Let $R$ be a local ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ and $M$ be finitely generated an $R$-module. Let $a\in\mathfrak{m}$ be a nonzero divisor of $M$. Then show that $d(M/aM)=d(M)-1$, where $d(M)$ is the degree of the polynomial type function $P_\mathfrak{m}(M,-)$ with $P_\mathfrak{m}(M,n)=l_R(M/\mathfrak{m}^nM)$.
I have proved that $d(M/aM)\leq d(M)-1$. Here is the proof of this:
$0\longrightarrow aM/(aM\cap \mathfrak{m}^nM)\longrightarrow M/\mathfrak{m}^nM\longrightarrow (M/aM)/(\mathfrak{m}^n(M/aM))\longrightarrow0$
So $\quad l_R(aM/(aM\cap \mathfrak{m}^nM)-P_\mathfrak{m}(M,n)+P_\mathfrak{m}(M/aM,n)=0$. Since $\{aM\cap\mathfrak{m}^nM\}$ is a stable $\mathfrak{m}$-filtration and $aM\simeq M$, it follows that $P_\mathfrak{m}(M,n)$ amd $l_R(aM/(aM\cap\mathfrak{m}^nM))$ have same degree and same leading coefficient. Hence $deg\;P_\mathfrak{m}(M/aM,-)< deg\;P_\mathfrak{m}(M,-)$ i.e. $d(M/aM)\leq d(M)-1$.
Can anyone give some hint in order to prove the opposite inequality without using the fact $\deg P_\mathfrak{m}(M,n)=\dim M=s(M)$ ?

Can we assume that $M$ is finitely generated over $R$?
If so, then there there's a theorem which says that $P_{\mathfrak{m}}(M,n) = \dim(M) = s(M)$, where $s(M):=\inf \{d | \exists a_1,...,a_d\in \mathfrak{m} \text{ with } l(\frac{M}{(a_1,...,a_d)M})<\infty \}$.
It's clear from this definition that $s(M)\leq 1+s(M/aM)$.
Edit: Consider the exact sequence $0\rightarrow aM\rightarrow M\rightarrow M/aM\rightarrow 0$.
Then we get an exact sequence similar to your first proof:
$0\rightarrow aM/(aM\cap \mathfrak{m}^nM)\rightarrow M/\mathfrak{m}^nM\rightarrow M/(aM+\mathfrak{m}^nM)\rightarrow 0$.
Since $M/(aM+\mathfrak{m}^nM)\cong M/aM\otimes_R R/\mathfrak{m}^n$, we have that $P_\mathfrak{m}(M,n) = P_{\mathfrak{m}}(M/aM,n)+l(aM/(aM\cap \mathfrak{m}^nM))$ (for large $n$).
Since $a$ is a nonzero divisor, $aM/(aM\cap \mathfrak{m}^nM)\cong M/N_n$ where $N_n = \text{Ann}_{M/\mathfrak{m}^nM}(a)$.
Now $N_n$ certainly contains $\mathfrak{m}^{n-1}M$, and so $l(M/N_n)\leq l(M/\mathfrak{m}^{n-1}M) = P_{\mathfrak{m}}(M,n-1)$.
Hence $P_{\mathfrak{m}}(M,n)\leq P_{\mathfrak{m}}(M/aM,n) + P_{\mathfrak{m}}(M,n-1)$. Hence $d(M)\leq d(M/aM) +1$.
(This makes sense since $P_\mathfrak{m}(M,n)-P_\mathfrak{m}(M,n-1)$ is supposed to be $\dim(M)-1$)

That Theorem btw is 3.33 here: https://faculty.sites.iastate.edu/jmccullo/files/inline-files/Math619.pdf, and your problem is a special case of Exercise 3.43

Can we prove it without using the fact $P_\mathfrak{m}(M,n)=dim,M=s(M)$ ? @WyattKuehster

I can think of a way to do it only using that $\dim(M) \leq  P_{\mathfrak{m}}(M,n)$ and that $\dim(M)-1\leq \dim(M/aM)$ which is a little less, but I'm trying to think of how you do it using only the Hilbert -Samuel polynomial...

I have not done yet. It is given in the exercise (before introducing krull dimension) of a book.

Interesting. I guess I've always thought of the Hilbert polynomial definition as "fancier" than the other definitions of dimension. What book is it?
